# Relationship not working. Foreach. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

So I have defined relationship between `OrderProduct.php` and 'Product.php' models like this:

`OrderProduct.php`:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

`Product.php`

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\OrderProduct');
}
```

`OrderController` function

```
public function orderShow($id)
{
    //$order = Order::where('id', $id)->first();
    $products = OrderProduct::where('id', 32)->first();
    return view('admin.orders.show', compact('order', 'products'));
}
```

When I do this foreach:

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
                    <?php dd($product) ?>
 @endforeach
```

I get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` How to fix this ?

Comment: OrderProduct::where('id', '32')->first(); ---> Only calling one product.

Comment: <?php dd($product) ?> --> die and dump = exit code

Comment: @labas GamePage your problem solved by below ansrwes but i want to give you suggestion that: You define belongsTo() in both model . Use hasMany() or hasOne() in any one of both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got only first record from set.
Try

```
public function orderShow($id)
{
    //$order = Order::where('id', $id)->get();
    $products = OrderProduct::where('id', 32)->get();
    return view('admin.orders.show', compact('order', 'products'));
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to retrieve particular record by *id*, use `find()` or even `findOrFail()` method (difference you can find in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-single-models));

```
public function orderShow($id)
{
    // this will retrieve record with id=32 from db if it exists,
    // and throw Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundExceptio otherw
    $product = OrderProduct::findOrFail(32);

    return view( 'admin.orders.show', compact('product') );
}
```

then in your blade template you can access your `$product` info as an object, like so

```
{{ $product->name }}
{{ $product->otherProductProperty }}
```

Comment: Okay now no error. But I still dont get any products info.

Comment: put `{{ dd($products) }}`in your blade, and show us what will you see. It must be a `Collection` instance/

Comment: `Collection {#254 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: It happens cause you have no record with _id_ = 32 in your database.

Comment: Well I have the records

Comment: Try to retrieve them `$products = OrderProduct::all();`. And you'll see that code works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114016/discussion-between-labas-gamepage-visogero-and-huuuk).

Comment: you need use `order_id` in where clause
`$products = OrderProduct::where('order_id', 32)->get()`;

Answer (score 0):

You are giving

```
$products = OrderProduct::where('id', 32)->first();
```

which will fetch you only one record the result will not be a collection so you cannot do foreach for this

You can change it as

```
$products = OrderProduct::where('id', 32)->get();
```

to make it work

You need to even check the Relationship used. One will be belongs to and the other will be hasmany

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this..

```
 public function orderShow($id)
    {
        //$order = Order::where('id', $id)->get();
        $products = OrderProduct::where('id', 32)->with('product')->get();
        return view('admin.orders.show', compact('order', 'products'));
    }
```